# Sliding square puzzle rectangle version

Tags: algorithm, proof

I am working on solvability problem. I realize that not every permutation is possible to solve. Even more I found algorithm for checking if permutation is possible to solve.

Algorithm: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/15Puzzle.html

Algorithm with proof: https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html

I want to know if this algorithm will work for rectangle version of puzzles and if not how to check it. Anyone can help?

#### Edit - Solution

Finally I found an analysis for rectangle puzzle sliding game. Everything is explained here: http://kevingong.com/Math/SixteenPuzzle.html

Comment: Have you tested it? Or tried to work through the proof to see if there's any step that would require the board to be square? (AFAIK, there isn't, but it's been a while since I last looked at it.)

Comment: Both links contain examples based on squares and operates on `n` symbol which is size of square. I want to know what happen when I have `n` and `m` where `n != m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizations of the 15-puzzle on arbitrary graphs were studied by Richard M. Wilson (citation below). By Theorem 1, since rectangular grid graphs are bipartite, the inversions criterion applies.

> Richard M Wilson, Graph puzzles, homotopy, and the alternating group,
>   Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B, Volume 16, Issue 1,
>   February 1974, Pages 86-96, ISSN 0095-8956,
>   http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(74)90098-7.
>   (//www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895674900987)